# How do you read text from a file then sort it in decending order?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have just started to learn Python and I have written the code for a dice game, I have saved the highscores in a text file and at the end, i want to output the top 5 highscores.

i have saved each score in the text file with this structure: name : score

Here is the code ive written:

```
file = open ("DiceGameScores","r")
for line in file:
    file_line = line.split(": ")
    value = file_line[-1]
    print (value)
    scores = value
print (scores)

mylist = []
mylist.extend (scores)
print (mylist)

mylist.sort(reverse = True)
print (mylist[0:5])

file.close()
```

i've outputted the scores and the list to check and when i run it i get this:

```
62

58

57

44

46

46

['4', '6', '\n']
['6', '4', '\n']
```

46 is the most recent highscore
the program is putting each digit as a value of the list and its accepting the new line (\n) part of the code

How do i get the top 5 highscores in order and as whole numbers please?

Comment: Please give an example of what your text file looks like.

Comment: Do you need to output the name as well? otherwise put the scores in a list and sort the list.

Comment: @Daniel yes i need to output the name with the score

Comment: @M-Chen-3 the text file is just the name of the user, a space, then a colon, another space then the score

Comment: `mylist.extend(scores)` should be `mylist.append(int(scores))` and moved inside the loop

Comment: @Tomerikoo thank you that allowed the whole score to go into the list but I am still unsure of how to put all of the scores into one list

Comment: What do you mean? Like I said, with `append`... Define an empty list before the loop and `append` each score inside the loop

Comment: @Tomerikoo sorry i forgot to define the empty list before the loop - thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two main problems are:

- Using `extend`...
- ... outside the loop.

[`extend`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) takes an iterable (the string from the file in that case) and adds ***all its elements*** to the list. This is why you get `['4', '6']`. Apart from that you get only one number because you do that outside the loop. You need to add the whole number using `append` and do so ***inside*** the loop. You should also convert the scores to ints for proper sorting:

```py
mylist = []
with open("DiceGameScores","r") as file:
    for line in file:
        file_line = line.split(':')
        value = file_line[-1]
        print (value)
        mylist.append(int(value))
    
print(mylist)

mylist.sort(reverse=True)
print(mylist[:5])
```

---

Note the use of [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) to open the file - this is the idiomatic way of handling files in Python. A lot better than using `open/close`. Embrace it!

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas you can read the file into a dataframe and then display the number of scores such as

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data.txt",sep=':', header=None)
df.columns = ["name","score"]
df.sort_values("score", inplace=True, ascending=False)
df.iloc[:3]
```

displays the top 3 scores

```
    name    score
3   d       78
2   c       67
1   b       56
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to declare a list outside of the loop. Then append the updated `score` to your list. The rest of the code as you.

```
file = open("DiceGameScores", "r")
mylist = []
for line in file:
    file_line = line.split(": ")
    value = file_line[1]
    print(alue)
    scores = value
    print(scores)
    mylist.append(scores)


print(mylist)
mylist.sort(reverse=True)
print(mylist[0:5])
```